# RS485 bus on raspberry pi extension board to DMX 512 protocol

Tags: raspberry-pi, led, rs485, dmx512

For my thesis I need to change brightness and color of LED stripes. In my case i have to use a raspberry pi with an raspberry pi extension board, because this board supports the RS485 bus system. I need to reprogramm the RS485 bus to DMX512 protocoll. The problem is that I don't know how to do this. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I have written a DMX512 Receiver for the Raspberry baremetal. Maybe it is helpful for you.
Description : https://sites.google.com/site/rpidmx512/raspberry-pi-dmx512-rdm
Source code : https://github.com/vanvught/rpidmx512

Comment: Thank you very much, but actually I was looking for a solution to implement THIS color-wheel (http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-as-a-DMX-light-controller/?lang=de) into a web-application (HTML). I got the same DMX Controller, all I have to do is change the colors of the LED stripe via HTML web-app!